# Should I put insulation in my basement bathroom

Tags: concrete, insulation, basement

I'm working on my basement bathroom. It's on an exterior wall that is concrete foundation. It has some existing (bad) insulation over the foundation wall. Some sort of rigid foam in between flat studs with some tar backing up against concrete. It also has wooden board boarded over with million nails for whatever reason. I decided to not rip it all out as it was super time consuming and frustrating, and after inspecting there were some insulation going on behind it I left it alone.
[image]

I've since then framed a wall about 1" away from all that and now I'm wondering whether I should put any insulation between my studs, either fiberglass or roxul. Picture is of tub shower wall, it's going to get schluter kerdi wall for waterproofing. Would that setup and what's currently on the foundation create a moisture trap? Would I be better off not insulating my studs at all?

Comment: Should also mention that I'm in Vancouver, BC, which would be same as climate zone 4 I believe in the US. Basement as a whole has been dry all year round

Comment: Insulation is cheap and you will likely never get another chance. It saves heat and makes the interior more comfortable. You should have a reliable vapor barrier on the bathroom wall.

Comment: thanks. My concern is mostly around the insulation being sandwiched between kerdi(waterproof membrane) and rigid foam against concrete. Would that create an environment for mold to grow?

Comment: I read about sprayed foam being used for basement insulation - this would completely eliminate any air gaps between the insulation and the wall. Might be an option.